# Where does the word "pragma" come from?

Tags: c++, c, terminology, pragma

So I know what pragma is, and what it's used for, but what is the meaning of the word itself? I've used it many times in code, but I never really knew what the word actually means or stands for.

Comment: It has roots in the Greek term πραγμα, which is the root of "pragmatic".  That's the best I can tell you.

Comment: +1 I've always wondered this but for some reason never thought to ask here.

Comment: Hmmm... what's the root of the word "wonder"? Can we have a etymology overflow, please?

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth How is this off topic?  It's programming related.

Comment: @Firoso, how does knowing the answer to this make you a better programmer? What's the etymology of the word 'function'? wOOt!! Now I know and I can write better functions. (not)  I'm not saying that it's not interesting, just that it doesn't belong here.

Comment: Hey, folks, pragmas are programming-related. Fair 'nuff to wonder where the term comes from and ask your peers in professional software development, isn't it?

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth, read the FAQ, this doesn't qualify as off topic. Also does knowing who Ada Lovelace was make you a better programmer? no? then why is she mentioned in every CS curriculum I'm aware of.

Comment: Asking about the meaning and/or lineage of a word is not programming-related just because that word happens to be used in programming. That's what [dictionaries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pragma) are for, not SO.

Comment: Knowing the natural-language origin of a programming keyword is akin to being fluent in the natural-language from which a programming language draws keywords. E.g., wouldn't you be a slightly better programmer if you knew English and could be clued in quicker to the intent behind "continue", "return", etc?

Comment: Then again, I could argue that being well rounded and having hobbies also makes you a better programmer. And I wouldn't want questions about your garden here.

Comment: @Firoso: 'Cause CS curricula are written by academics who (as a class) are concerned about priority and the proper apportionment of credit and generally keeping certain names around? On top of which she's one of a fairly small set of big *female* names from the early days, which is of some importance these days, too.

Comment: @gnovice: He's not asking about non-programming uses of a programming word, but the history in the context of programming.  E.g. "Why does C call them 'functions'?" vs. "Someone said 'the function of a motor is..', what is 'function'?"  Perhaps the question text could be improved.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=pragma

Comment: @Jon: No hits for pragma, just pragmatism and pragmatic.

Comment: @Roger: I know. Just putting in my two cents and sharing a plug for a site I like.

Comment: Didn't think this would cause such a stink, but thanks for the great answers everyone!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

According to a US Government-owned(!) document describing the design of Ada: [*Rationale for the Design of the
Ada® Programming Language*](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83rat/html/ratl-02-01.html) :

> A pragma (from the Greek word meaning
>   action) is used to direct the actions
>   of the compiler in particular ways,
>   but has no effect on the semantics of
>   a program (in general).

I like the (last caveat) there...

This cross references well with on-line greek dictionaries (e.g. as quoted by [Martin York](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791259/where-does-the-word-pragma-come-from/3791427#3791427)) that say pragma (*πράγμα*, as commented on the original question by asveikau) [means](http://www.studylight.org/lex/grk/view.cgi?number=4229):

1. that which has been done, a deed, an accomplished fact
2. what is done or being accomplished

   1. spec. business, a commercial transaction
3. a matter, question, affair

   1. spec. in a forensic sense, a matter at law, case, suit
4. that which is or exists, a thing

Seems the key to understanding is the word *action* rather than *information*.

Answer (score 18):

In mathematics and logic, a pragma is a given, a fact, a prerequisite to the argument, problem, or proof which follows.

Answer (score 17):

Pulled right from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_(programming))(programming):

> In Ada, compiler directives are called pragmas (short for "pragmatic information").

While it's not explicitly for C, this should answer your question anyway. However, as T.J. pointed out, there is no valid source given for this piece of information.

Comment: Mind, that article doesn't cite *any* original sources...and searching on A Famous Web Search Engine for "+pragma +pragmatic +ada" turns up a very, very short list of clearly non-canonical sites. Doesn't mean it's not true.

Comment: You're absolutely right, a source would be most appreciated. Still, I guess it's best to leave the answer unless I'm proven wrong.

Answer (score 7):

From the ancient Greek:

> pragma: a thing done, a fact

As with all things geeky, somebody was trying to be way too clever for their own good. Unfortunately its original meaning becomes lost to the rest of us (unless you have Google and a Latin/Greek to English dictionary handy).

http://www.studylight.org/lex/grk/view.cgi?number=4229
http://www.bibletools.org/index.cfm/fuseaction/Lexicon.show/ID/G4229/pragma.htm

Original (that is what the above page says, but I don't have a copy of that book):

> Thayer and Smith. "Greek Lexicon entry for Pragma". "The New Testament Greek Lexicon".

Answer (score 3):

The programming language Ada was quite possibly the first compiler to use pragma to specify preprocessor directives.  The word was used as a shortened form of "pragmatic information"

When the C programming language was designed it didn't initially have pragma directives, but was quickly added to the specification to support custom compiler features. (ie. #pragma optimization_level for the intel C++ compiler)

Since then many languages have implemented pragma in some form or another, including C#, but they are often limited to build time warnings and optimization hints.

One of the most common and useful pragmas, in non-standard C and C++, is [#pragma once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) used to specify that a file should only be included once.