# The directive #pragma, why it is called as such?

Tags: c++

The directive `#pragma`, is it an abbreviation? If, then it is stand for what and why it is called as such?

Comment: Google gives a host of results for this among the best are [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805(VS.71).aspx) and [Wikipedia](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%23pragma%20&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPragma&ei=krGrTtLOE4K5hAfruuTHDw&usg=AFQjCNHHGAhmWm8FtCL2bVw-WmHpKfJsrA)

Comment: `#pragma` is for pragmatic programmers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does the word "pragma" come from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791259/where-does-the-word-pragma-come-from)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pragmatic modules, or pragmata, for short, or pragmas, for shorter affect the compilation of your program.

It is called this way because the compiler needs to treat it pragmatically.

Pragmas were introduced in the [Ada 83](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-02-08.html#2.8) in 1983, and were reused in many computer languages since (C, perl, ECMAScript, PL/SQL...)

The naming rationale appears in the document "[Rationale for the Design of the
Ada® Programming Language](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83rat/html/ratl-02-01.html)".

The term *pragmatism* is derived from the Greek word *pragma* - *πράγμα*, meaning action, from which the words ‘practice’ and ‘practical’ come.

The Pragmatism movement was introduced into philosophy by Mr. Charles Peirce in 1878, and named "Pragmatism" by William James in 1898.

Comment: +1 know your greek roots

Comment: Do you have a source for "pragma" being a contraction of "pragmatic"? I always assumed that it came from the Greek word directly, and that descriptions in which the handling of pragmas is called "pragmatic" are sometimes re-formations of that English word with a new meaning somewhat more closely related to the etymology, and sometimes puns.

Comment: Thanks for the link -- so if that applies to C as well as Ada 83, then it is direct from "pragma", not a contraction.

Answer (score 0):

As written by ALs, but you have to delve a little more in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_%28programming%29):

> Another C construct, the #pragma directive, is used to instruct the compiler to use **pragmatic** or **implementation-dependent** features. Two most notable users of this directive are OpenMP and OpenHMPP

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the compiler could ignore `#pragma`-s and your program would still behave like it does with them. In practice, the evil is in the details and it is not that simple (there are dirty exceptions).

And you usually don't need `#pragma`-s. I coded in C for 30 years and almost never used them.